# Connecting LEDs to a 9V battery

Tags: led, batteries, resistance, parallel

1) I have 6 4.5V 20mA LEDs and have connected them to a common 9V battery. Doing this I made 3 parallel circuits with 2 LEDs in each.

Now, I see that most pages that describe LED circuitry say that you should always have a resistor in the circuit. In my case, do I need one? Why?

This is a hobby project, but the LEDs are sealed in glue so fixing a blown bulb would be a big hassle. I'd rather have them live for as long as possible.

2) If I happened to have the same circuit as above, but with 3.4V 20mA LEDs instead, is it likely that the LEDs would blow quickly? The LEDs are of a cheap type:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/20pcs-5mm-Clear-White-LEDs-Ultra-Bright-LED-DIY-/190642214244?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2c63295564#ht_3051wt_1156

Comment: NO Ls are 4.5V - where did you get that figure? See table on page you cited. You MUST use a resistor or constant current source. Note that 9V battery drops to ~=6V when almost flat.

Comment: The ebay page you linked shows that the white LEDs have a forward voltage of 3.2 - 3.4 V. What makes you think its okay to apply 4.5 V to them?

Comment: And even if they were rated for 4.5 V, since the current is exponential you would still risk to push a too high current (and now you are doing that). A resistor is recommended in any case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What would the current be if I plug an LED into a perfect circuit](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23084/what-would-the-current-be-if-i-plug-an-led-into-a-perfect-circuit)

Comment: I'm sitting here with a packet of 5V LEDs right in front of me. Plus a bag full of the ones in the ebay-link. Plus a whole range of other ones. That part of the question was related to which LEDs I should choose for my project!

Comment: A "5 V LED" might have a resistor built in to the package with it. Or it might be something else. We can't know unless you give us the datasheet for the part.

Comment: A datasheet doesn't exist. My question was simply that intuitively it sounds like 2*4.5V LEDs in series on a 9V battery won't need a resistor. Not whether 4.5V LEDs are common. Nobody has answered that question yet, although Lyndon's answer below was descriptive and touched the subject.

Comment: Everybody have answered the question: think to the LED like a device that (in this case) is off with Vled<4.5V; then, if Vled>=4.5V, it starts sinking all the current that you give to it. So in this way, you don't know how much current you give to the LED, and you risk the magic smoke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally the LEDs should be driven by a constant-current circuit. This will maintain a constant brightness and color as the battery drains, or as the LEDs heat up or cool down.

But the real world isn't ideal, so you can often get away by just using resistors. Yes, you should definitely use them. The resistors are there to limit the current through the LED and keep them from overheating and burning up. A 9V battery has a fairly high internal resistance, so you may be able to get away with two in series and no resistor, but it will be unreliable (changing to a different brand of battery could be enough to blow out the LEDs, etc.)

For the worst case of two white LEDs in series running at 20mA, the lowest forward voltage shown in your link is 3.2V, so you would have (9 - 6.4)/.02 = 130 ohms. The current is low, so a 1/4 watt resistor will be fine. Select the closest value to this you can find. Running at 20mA the LEDs will be pretty bright and this is a benefit: as the battery drains or the LED forward voltage changes, the apparent brightness probably won't change that much. Human vision is more sensitive to dim lights and it's harder to tell that a bright light has changed 10% than a dim light has changed 10%.

Comment: Consider that he might have red LEDs, that have a drop of 1.8-2.2 V; you may add also the values for that kind of LED.

Comment: Nope, I have three types of LEDs - 3.4V, 4.5V and 5V. I think I'll go for the 3.4V ones since I have so many of them.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need a series resistor. The reason is that the LED voltage isn't exactly 4.5V, and it also varies with current. Having a series resistor is the only way to be sure you supply the right amount of current. You need some voltage drop across the resistor, however, so putting two LEDs in series is out. You need 4.5V across the resistor for 20mA so

> \$R = \dfrac{9V - 4.5V}{20mA} = 220\Omega\$

A 9V battery can't supply very much current, but without series resistor the current may still be too much for the LEDs. I'm currently working with white LEDs with a typical current of 20mA, which have only 25mA as maximum.

**edit** (re your comment)
In theory you could do without resistor, but the LEDs are never exactly 4.5V and your battery is never exactly 9V. If the battery's voltage decreases to 8.9V your LEDs will light (much) dimmer, or (much) brighter if the LEDs' voltage is 4.4V, since the current will be much higher, and maybe become too high.

Comment: Yes, but my question was related to TWO LEDs in series. That would make your equation R = (9V - 2*4.5V)/20mA = 0Ω. And this is henceforth the core of my question. Can I get away with not using a resistor in this case?

Comment: @Pedery - Edited my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Resistors it is then :)

Comment: @Pedery - Like others have commented 4.5V is very odd for a LED, so it's possible that the resistor is integrated. In that case the LED's voltage is lower and the resistor is calculated to bridge the difference between 4.5V and the LED's actual voltage. The best way to test this is to apply a variable voltage and decrease it from 4.5V. If at 4.3V or 4.2V you still have more or less the same brightness the resistor is integrated.

Comment: I see. One of my "odd" LEDs is a blinking one, so it probably has an IC. As for the other ones I don't know, and I don't have a variable power source. Anyway, this is a pet project, so no biggie. I'll go for the common 3.4V LEDs, add a resistor, and problem solved :)